# Is there a JavaScript minifier with conditional directives?

Tags: javascript, minify, conditional-compilation

I'm looking for a JavaScript minifier which will have some kind of support for something similar to [conditional compilation directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691099%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

So for example, the original JavaScript code could look like something similar to this:

```
//#if Dev
    showLoginScreen();
//#else
    login("DevUser", "qwerty1");
//#endif
```

So the original code could contain a directive `#define Dev` but once it goes into production that `#define Dev` would be removed, and the minifier would exclude the line `login("DevUser", "qwerty1");` from its output.

Do any minifiers support this kind of behavior?

Comment: I don't know about a *minifier* having this functionality, but I think it's quite common to do something like this in your server-side language of choice before supplying input to a minifier. Basically like what is already done all the time with generated HTML (e.g., via Ruby with .erb files or PHP with .php files).

Comment: The Closure Compiler supports define's.

Comment: @Stephen Chung - Can you link to any resources about using The Closure Compiler with `define`s?

Comment: You can go to the main Closure compiler home page and read the docs.  You can do a @define in JsDoc notation and then set the variable in the command line using the --define switch.

Comment: @Stephen Chung - It looks like closure supports a different kind of `define`, [one which can override variable values](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler.html#tag-define). That's not what I'm looking for; I need conditional compilation. I want code removed from the final output based on the `define`.

Comment: Well, put a `@define` variable in your code, then use that variable in an if-statement wrapping conditional code. When you compile, the Closure Compiler automatically excludes your code if the variable is false.  This is one of the many uses of `@define`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just run the code through the C preprocessor, then run that output through the minifier. The C preprocessor isn't really C-specific beyond its handling of string literals.

Example:

```
cpp -DDev file.js /dev/stdout | jsmin > file-min.js
```

where file.js is:

```
#if Dev
    showLoginScreen();
#else
    login("DevUser", "qwerty1");
#endif
```

will include the Dev code and then minify it.

In order to make the original source code executable as-is, you can add one more step to the processing pipeline. Write your code like this:

```
//#if Dev
    showLoginScreen();
//#else
    login("DevUser", "qwerty1");
//#endif
```

and then process it like this:

```
sed 's!^//#!#!' file.js | cpp -DDev /dev/stdin /dev/stdout | jsmin > file-min.js
```

The `sed` portion serves to strip the leading `//` from lines beginning with `//#`. `cpp` then preprocesses the source as normal, and the output from `cpp` is fed through `jsmin` for minification.

A better solution is probably just to do as C programmers do and always preprocess your source file appropriately before running. You might edit a `.jspp` ("pre-process JavaScript") file, and have your system set up to preprocess it appropriately for development or deployment whenever you change things. If you're using frequent testing, you can make the preprocessing part of your test tool's invocation.

(NOTE: The command line might be off; I worked out the cpp part from the manpage and the jsmin part from the jsmin.c source code file, so I haven't actually tested this command line.)

Comment: Yes. I have expanded my answer to try to provide a more complete example.

Comment: But then the original JavaScript can't be executed on account of the `#` characters (it isn't minified when in the dev environment) but if I put them in comments, cpp seems to ignore them.

Comment: Correct. You don't run the original JavaScript any more; you run it through the preprocessor. It doesn't make sense to run the original, because you are introducing an if/else: if you wanted both to run, then you wouldn't need the if/else construct. If you do want to be able to run the Javascript as-is, then it's time for another step in your preprocessing toolchain: write `//#` in your code, and then use sed to globally replace line-initial `//#` with just `#`, then run that output through cpp.

Comment: k... I also found this: http://www.nongnu.org/espresso/js-cpp.html - its comment line is working well for me.

Comment: ... I'm going to hold out on accepting though, as I need the original files to still be executable. (apologies!)

Comment: @Richard: Doesn't the `sed` solution address that?

Comment: Ah yes! Forgot about your comment... looking into it now :)

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the C preprocessor and a few other contenders based on answers to similar questions. Then found what I think is the best answer by far - PHP. Consider:

1) PHP is indeed a preprocessor (it's in the acronym).

2) PHP is ready to go on most servers. All you have to do is either change your file extensions from ".js" to ".php" or ".js.php", or (my preference), make a simple edit to a config file (you can find the details elsewhere).

3) Many JavaScript developers are already familiar with, or expert at, PHP.

4) PHP is Turing-complete, unlike many other preprocessors.

5) You only need basic PHP knowledge to benefit a lot.

6) There is way more documentation/tutorials/forums for PHP than other preprocessors.

But mostly, it's so weird it's cool. Thanks to whoever gave me the idea - I can't find their post at the moment.